Every finitely generated and torsion free $A$-module is free when $A$ is PID

If $A$ is a commutative ring with identity and a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated and torsion free $A$-module, then $M$ is free.

I am trying to solve this excercise from my Commutative algebra book. In order to do it, the book gives the reader a way to follow:


Prove that if $M$ is a submodule of $A^{(n)}$ (where $A^{(n)}$ denotes the direct sum of $n$ copies of $A$), $M$ is free.
Given $M$ an $A$-module, denote by $T(M)=\{ m \in M \, | \, \exists a \in A \setminus \{0\} : am = 0 \}$ . Prove that $T(M) = \{0\} \iff \forall a \in A, \mu_a(x) = ax$ is monomorphism.
Given $M$ a finitely generated and torsion free $A$-module, denote by $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^s \subset M$ its generators. If $r \leq s$ satisfies that $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^r$ is maximal respect the linear independence relation, then $N = \langle x_k  \rangle_{k=1}^r$ is free and there is $a \in A$ with $aM \subset N$ .


For 1, I proceed by induction. If $n=1$, then $M$ is an ideal of $A$ and since $A$ is a principal ideal domain, there is $x \in A: M = Ax$. Via $f: A \rightarrow M, a \mapsto ax$, it is clear that $M$ is free.
Suppose that $n \in \Bbb{N} , n \geq 2$ satisfies 1. Let $f: A^{(n)} \rightarrow A^{(n+1)}, (x_1, \dots ,  x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots , x_n, 0)$ and $g: A^{(n+1)} \rightarrow A, (x_1, \dots , x_{n+1}) \mapsto x_{n+1}$ . It is easy to see that
$$ 0 \rightarrow A^{(n)} \xrightarrow{f} A^{(n+1)} \xrightarrow{g} A \rightarrow 0$$
is exact. Then, for every $M$ submodule of $A^{(n+1)}$:
$$ 0 \rightarrow f^{-1}(M) \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} g(M) \rightarrow 0$$
is also exact. In particular, since $f$ is linear, $f^{-1}(M)$ is submodule of $A^{(n)}$ and then it is free. Therefore, since $M \cong f^{-1}(M)$ via $f$, we have that $M$ is free.
For 2, if $T(M) = \{0\}$, given $a \in A$ and $m \in \ker \mu_a \implies am = 0 \implies m \in T(M) \implies m= 0$. Conversely, given $m \in T(M)$, it exists $a \in A \setminus \{0\} : am = 0 \implies m \in \ker \mu_a \implies m = 0$ .
In order to prove 3, I have thought about prove that $M$ is isomorphic to $A^{(s)}$ and then apply (1) to conclude that $N$ is free, but I am not reaching anything since it is a little confusing to me yet and also I do not have ideas on how to prove the existence of $a$, so any possible help would be appreciated or correction to what I do on 1 and 2 would be appreciated.

Have you used the 'maximal respect to the linear independence relation' part? I think the statement on this condition is a bit unclear here. The selected 'maximal' set of generators is maximal in the sense of set of linear independent elements, not in the sense of maximal r. You can select this maximal linearly independent set arbitrarily from M, not necessarily from ${x_k}$ you initially began with, and they will work like a basis of a vector space. Furthermore you can prove maximal linear independent subset of these generators is actually maximal in M.

There's a problem with the proof of 1. You cannot say that $M \cong f^{-1}(M)$. Instead try to show that $M \cong f^{-1}(M) \oplus g(M)$. Also, if you know the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over a PID, maybe you can come up with an easier proof of this problem?

@AprilGrimoire Uhm, I see. The problem then is, $N$ would be free because the $N \rightarrow A^{(r)}, x_k \mapsto e_k$ is an isomorphism? And how I should proceed to find $a$ ?

@RHspqr I have two questions if I do not bother you. First, $f$ is in fact a monomorphism, and if we restrict it to $f^{-1}(M)$ we have that $f(f^{-1}(M))=M$ so $f|_M$ would be an isomorphism, that is what I thought first, what is wrong then? Second, it is enought to define $\phi : f^{-1} (M) \oplus g(M) \rightarrow M, (x, g(y)) \mapsto f(x) + y $ in order to prove what you say?

@Superdivinidad for the first problem, why not try $M = 0 \oplus \dots \oplus0 \oplus A$? In this case the preimage of $M$ is in fact zero. For the second, yes it suffices to use this map and the five lemma to conclude.

@Superdivinidad Yeah $N$ is free. To find $a$, work on each generator of $M$, and use the maximal-linear-independent-set property. It is like working with a basis of a vector space. Then taking product will give an $a$ working for all of $M$, since $M$ is f.g. .
